# Understanding the Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model's caveat for HEAD and GET request before creating the object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am reading the Amazon S3 data consistency from the docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html

> Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new
>   objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat
>   is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if
>   the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides
>   eventual consistency for read-after-write.

I understand that Amazon S3 provides read after write consistency while putting new objects to S3 bucket. But I didn't quite get that caveat for HEAD and GET request before creating the object, what does that mean?

Comment: [Werner Vogels on Eventual Consistency](http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2008/12/eventually_consistent.html) -- mostly about DynamoDB, but still relevant for any eventually consistent system.

Answer (score 15):

The actual internals of S3 are proprietary to AWS, but here's a theory:

When you request an object, it goes to its cache to see if it's there.

1. If it is not in the cache, it pulls the data from the underlying storage and puts it in the cache.

This is the read-after-write consistency. You'll get the new version immediately.

2. If it is already in the cache, it returns the data.

This is the eventual consistency for read-after-write for **updates**. You update the object, and then the cached version must expire before you get the new version.

3. If it is not in the cache, and the object is not there, it caches the "not present" result.

This is the behaviour you're asking about. Like the old data being in the cache, S3 has cached "the key does not exist" as the "old data". So again, you must wait for the cache to expire before the actual data can be returned.

Again, this is not stated with any authority. I'd welcome any S3 experts to correct or dispute any errors I may have.

Comment: It really can't be any other way than exactly as you have described it.  In essence, a `GET` or `HEAD` request for a nonexistent object changes the index replica's internal representation of the object from "unknown, I will have to ask the master index" to "I already asked the master index, and as a result, I know that the object does not exist, so 404."  Once the index insertion from the `PUT` has replicated, the object is accessible.  When not requested in advance, the index replica does a lookup and finds the new object on the first request.

Comment: This also explains the eventual consistency of overwrites and deletes.  Until the index replication is caught up, the old answer is used for satisfying requests.  The only discrepancy I suspect there may be with your answer is that I suspect only the index is what's cached.  The actual object is immediately accessible, since it is documented that a `200 OK` means the object is durable stored, and we know that S3 objects are stored in multiple places within the region... but the index being used to look it up is the entity that I suspect has a cache and a potential replication delay.